# Helm regex match from the beginning until the last occurance of a character

Tags: regex, kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

Struggling with Helm to match the word from its beginning to the last occurance of `-`.

I tried `{{- printf "%s" .Release.Name | regexFind "[^-]*$" -}}`, but it prints from the last occurrance to the end of the word.

**Expected**

input : `hello-world-here` => output: `hello-world`

input : `hello-world-here-and-there` => output : `hello-world-here-and`

Comment: Maybe `regexReplaceAll "-[^-]*$" - ""` instead of `regexFind`?

Comment: Why would you want `-here` to be eliminated in the first, but nothing eliminated in the second? I'm sorry, I can't what rule you want applied.

Comment: @Andreas you are right. it was typo. I updated the question

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is a good hint. Thank you

Comment: Does it work BTW?

Comment: no it does not work. it return nothing (empty string). There is a `-` at the middle. correct ?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `regexReplaceAll "-[^-]*$" ""`? The regex must work.

Comment: same .. empty string ☹️ `{{- printf "%s" .Release.Name | regexReplaceAll "-[^-]*$" "" -}}` .. release name is `ui-lool-local` BTW

Comment: Do you really need to add `-` at the end? I doubt it is required. Try `{{- printf "%s" .Release.Name | regexReplaceAll "-[^-]*$" "" }}`

Comment: does not work. this is my helm version : Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.1", GitCommit:"5270352a09c7e8b6e8c9593002a73535276507c0", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Comment: Ok, what about `{{- regexFind ".*-" .Release.Name | trimSuffix "-" -}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big thanks to [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) for his hints.

After a lot of investigation, I realized that the Regex is correct, but the signature of function is amazing :

```
{{- regexReplaceAll "-[^-]*$" .Release.Name "" -}}
```

and NOT :

```
 {{- regexReplaceAll "-[^-]*$"  "" .Release.Name -}}
```

Comment: That is why I put `-` in between the regex and replacement patterns, I took it for an input variable in the piped notation.

Comment: To make it a bit more clear, the order of the arguments is: pattern, input string, replacement pattern.